# AlarmManager set up Android?

Tags: java, android

I have Alarm Manager which needs to repeat every 12 hours.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in = new Intent(this, myReceiver.class);
        myAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, in, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), time, myAlarmSender);
```

after that happen I catch trigger event in class myReceiver which extends Broadcast receiver

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

now I want to set up Status bar Notification or to start my notification class where I have code for notifications, but I'm not able to start new Intent or to write code for notifications inside of onReceive() method.
Help?
Thanks, Wolf.

Comment: Why not? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend the things I do for you:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

You'll want your AlarmManager to set your alarm in that it Starts a service. Then when your service is started you can show a notification.

Set the alarm:

```
public class AlarmTask implements Runnable{
    // The date selected for the alarm
    private final Calendar date;
    // The android system alarm manager
    private final AlarmManager am;
    // Your context to retrieve the alarm manager from
    private final Context context;

    public AlarmTask(Context context, Calendar date) {
        this.context = context;
        this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Request to start are service when the alarm date is upon us
        // We don't start an activity as we just want to pop up a notification into the system bar not a full activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Sets an alarm - note this alarm will be lost if the phone is turned off and on again
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

This will start a service `NotifyService`

Then in NotifyService class:

```
private void showNotification() {
        // This is the 'title' of the notification
        CharSequence title = &quot;Alarm!!&quot;;
        // This is the icon to use on the notification
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
        // This is the scrolling text of the notification
        CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us";
        // What time to show on the notification
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);

        // Clear the notification when it is pressed
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Send the notification to the system.
        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

        // Stop the service when we are finished
        stopSelf();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent bootintent)
{
    Intent anyService = new Intent(context, AnyService.class);
    context.startService(anyService);
}
```